# Ionic - Condição em que se o campo já existir ele será adicionado de novo

Tags: javascript, ionic, typescript

Tenho uma dúvida no ionic, estou tentando fazer que se o campo que no caso seria o CEP já estiver na tabela ele ira automaticamente preencher o resto com oque já foi digitado nesse CEP.

Home.page.ts

```js
export class HomePage {
  public cep;
  public endereco;
  public cidade;
  public uf;
  public campos =  [{cep: '5555',
  endereco:'99999', cidade: 'Itapeva', uf: 'SP'}
  ];


  adicionar():void{
    this.campos.push({cep: this.cep, endereco: this.endereco, cidade: this.cidade, uf: this.uf });
    
  }
}
```

Comment: Se tu usar FormGroup e FormBuilder, essa ação será possível. Qualquer dúvida posso postar um código pra te ajudar.